# created post displaying differently on front end

Tags: posts, theme-development

I have been having a problem with the styles on my custom blog theme that I'm making. When I create a post and then publish it what the post looks like in the back end is different to the front end, The back end is laid out nice and how I want and then in the front end it does not have line spaces/line breaks, Also images will not fully stretch to the full width of the what I have in the back end.

I did add these styles before to allow me to align images and that worked fine, but I am wondering if there is other styles I need to add to make the paragraphs have spaces in-between paragraphs
and able to full width the images.

```css
.alignleft {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.alignright {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.aligncenter {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I was looking at post format does that have something to do with it?

This is the php/html page it the single.php page.

```php
<?php 
get_header('internal');
while(have_posts()) {
    the_post(); ?>
    
    <div class="burger-menu-container">
      <ul class="burger-ul">
      <li class="burg-menu"><a class="burger-link" href="<?php echo site_url() ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li class="burg-menu"><a class="burger-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/blog') ?>">blog</a></li>
        <li class="burg-menu"><a class="burger-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/about-us') ?>">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="burg-menu"><a class="burger-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/contact-us') ?>">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="burg-menu"><a class="burger-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/private-policy') ?>">Privacy policy</a></li>
        <li class="burg-menu"><a class="burger-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/cookie-policy') ?>">Cookie policy</a></li>
        <li class="burg-menu"><a class="burger-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/site-map') ?>">Sitemap</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="copyright-container">
        <span class="hamberger-copyright">www.website.com © THE WEBSITE NAME 2020</span>
      </div> 
   </div>



    <div class="top-box-container">
      <div class="box-top-wrapper">
        <div class="box-top-container">
         <div><a class="toppy-one" href="<?php echo site_url('/blog') ?>"> <div class="top-box-one"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><p class="intro-blog-tab"> Blog Home</p></div></a></div>
         <div class="top-box-two box-single-page">Posted by<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> on <?php the_time('n.j.y') ?> in <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?></div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>

 </div>  

    <?php }
    ?>
     
     <div class="internal-middle-section-container">         
      <div class="internal-content">
       <div class="inner-content-container">
        <div class="internal-write"> <?php the_content() ?></div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>

 <!-- </div>   
</div> -->
    



    <?php 

get_footer('internal');
?>
```

here are the images of the editor in WordPress backend and the front end.

[image: view in the editor]

[image: This is the view of the front end]

In this example i not sure why the line breaks are not appearing on the front end.

any help I would be grateful thanks

Comment: Please link us to the malfunctioning page or show all of the code that's being affected, including the PHP/HTML. That's the best way for us to help you.

Comment: I have added the code of the effected page which is the single.php page to display the content of my posts and i added couple of images thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort the problem by adding this CSS to the bottom of my main-styles.css file

```css
p {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

It also fixed all the issues with the images that I mentioned above and the line breaks that were not appearing on the front end.
The WordPress editor and the front all marry up now.

Thanks